# M2 attribute handling, import , custom attributes

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute, importexport, custom-attributes

currently i use import/export for creating configurable products automatically. this is also quite a buch of work , because attributes aren't imported like in 1x.

The optional attributes section in the csv file is quite unhandy. i wonder if m2 developers have ever seen a productlist which a merchant from the manufaturer is normally receiving, especially the color and sizes of an article or adding a manufacturer attribute or fabric and whatever you can think about must get stuffed into one single csv field ?

furthermore if, for example the size, has a value which is not predefined in the attribute, import does not work -  you can add everything manually, then.

we are selling clothes, having more than 50 brands and every manufacturer uses different sizing, different colornames each season. so we have to add about 20.000 simple products and have to create about 5000 configurable semi-automatically using the import every half year.

currently we have in our old m1-shop about 500 different colors (there are the colorcombinations not included), about 300 different size-descriptions and some other fields with different values. each season == twice a year, everything gets new, new colors, new fabrics, etc .. i wonder, how i should manage that for the future, maybe using a differnet shop-system ?

Comment: You can check my answer here to create multiselect option on the fly based on the value fileld in the import file : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147179/magento-2-1-2-importing-multiselect-attribute-values-from-csv/147295#147295 It works for configurable product. Not tested with grouped or bundle products. I used this in order to create color variation on the fly.

Comment: Thank You,   but i guess i have a different problem.

i have about 50 different article lists to import every half year with many new differernt attributes which only can get imported if they exists prior to the import. so it can be that there are for larger csv-lists about 100 different colors newly created. (some of the lists have about 8000 articles - patagonia for example). therefor i would have to import somehow the attribute values first, but i dont know how.

Comment: colors are not the only attribute values, i need to add also fabric,  certificates, colorpatterns, etc ...
if i understand you correctly i would have to add a field flaue on the import script many attributes.. i guess i would exceed the field-lenghtbecause that are not only 2 or 3 values

Comment: So create a custom import for import the attributes + attribute options from a custom CSV. You can based on the Magento Import abstract class to implement a new profile.